# findining the smallest sum of squared lengths of the intervals I_{k}

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms

> Given a set S = { $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, . . . , $x_{n}$} where $x_{i} \in Z$ . and a K and it is  $Z^{+}$ .  The goal is to ﬁnd k intervals
> $I_{1}, I_{2}, . . . , I_{k}$ so that each $x_{i}$ is in one of the
> intervals $I_{j}$ and so that the sum of the squared lengths of the
> intervals $I_{k}$ is as small as possible. For instance, S = {1, 3, 6}
> and K = 2, the best outcome is $I_{1}$ = [1, 3], $I_{2}$ = [6, 6], and
> the sum of squares of the lengths is 4.
>
> We can approach our algorithm as: First of all, we sort S and let S =
> { $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, . . . , $x_{n}$} where  $x_{1}$<$x_{2}$<, . . . ,
> <$x_{n}$. Then we can use dynamic programming. We let L[i, m] be the
> shortest sum of squared lengths of m intervals that cover all of
> $x_{1}$, . . . , $x_{i}$. Notice that L[1, m] = 0 for all 1 ≤ m ≤ k
> and L[i, 1] = ($x_{i}$ − $x_{1})^2$ for 1 ≤ i ≤ n. If we have a cover
> of $x_{1}$, . . . , $x_{i}$, suppose the interval that covers
> $x_{i}$ also covers all points $x_{j}$ , $x_{j+1}$, . . . , $x_{i}$.
> Then, the sum of the squared lengths is at least ($x_{i}$ − $x_{j}$
> $)^2$ + L[i − 1, m − 1]. Therefore, the minimum such value is actually
> obtainable.

How can we know for sure "that L[1, m] = 0 for all 1 ≤ m ≤ k and L[i, 1] = $(x_{i} − x_{1})^2$ for 1 ≤ i ≤ n" and ?

Seem like we need to have a 2D-array? How can I visualize this solution better?

Here is what draw:
[image]

How can we fill the 2D array with ($x_{i}$ − $x_{j}$ $)^2$ + L[i − 1, m − 1] ?

Comment: Please credit the original source of this exercise and of all copied text/material.  Thank you!

Comment: We'd prefer that you ask only one question per post.  I see three different questions here.